# Let G be a group of permutations of a set S. Prove that the orbits of the members of S constitute a partition of S.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of permutations of a set $S$. Prove that the orbits of the members of $S$ constitute a partition of $S$.

Comment: Have you written down the relevant definitions, or is there something in particular giving you trouble?

Comment: Being in the same orbit is an equivalence relation on $S$, the equivalence classes are the orbits, and equivalence classes always form a partition.

Comment: @M.Van Wow ...Brilliant..Thanks.All proofs I saw were lengthy. This could be a proof right?...Just showing that it is an equivalence relation!!??

Comment: Yes, in fact, $G$ acts on $S$ by $\sigma x= \sigma(x)$ for $\sigma \in G$ and $x \in S$. It is a general fact, which is not difficult to prove, that $x$~$ y$ if and only if there is some $g \in G$ such that $x=gy$, is an equivalence relation. This holds for any group $G$ and any set $S$ on which $G$ acts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You should have no trouble verifying that the union of the orbits is all of $S$, so the real work is in showing that any two orbits are either identical or disjoint.

- Show that if $s,t\in S$, and $t\in\operatorname{orb}_G(s)$, then $\operatorname{orb}_G(t)\subseteq\operatorname{orb}_G(s)$.
- Show that for any $s,t\in S$, $t\in\operatorname{orb}_G(s)$ if and only if $s\in\operatorname{orb}_G(t)$.
- Conclude that if $s,t\in S$, and $t\in\operatorname{orb}_G(s)$, then $\operatorname{orb}_G(s)=\operatorname{orb}_G(t)$.
- Finally, note that if $s,t\in S$, and $\operatorname{orb}_G(s)\cap\operatorname{orb}_G(t)\ne\varnothing$, there is an $r\in S$ such that $r\in\operatorname{orb}_G(s)\cap\operatorname{orb}_G(t)$. Therefore ... ?